# linux find command : multiple searches in multiple directories

Tags: linux, syntax, find

It's possible withe parentheses syntax to run multiple searches :

```
find / \( search1 && search2 \)
```

It's possible to run one search in multiple directories with :

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 search
```

Is it possible to run a search according to the encountered directory something like :

```
find / \( /bin search1 \) \( /usr/bin search2 \)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-path` filter.

```
find / \( -path '/bin/*' search1 \) -o \( -path '/usr/bin/*' search2 \)
```